# An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' thrown in ASP.Net program

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to get a list of league games and am getting

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

My code for the view is as follows:

```
public ActionResult viewSchedule(int? id)
{
    int leagueId = (int)id;
    int seasonYear = getSeasonYear();

    League league = db.Leagues.Find(leagueId);
    var leagueGames = db.Games.Where(l => l.League == league).Where(g => g.SeasonDate == seasonYear);

    return View(leagueGames.ToList());         
}
```

and the view model is:

> @model IEnumerable

Comment: So at what line is the exception thrown? Are `League` etc. custom classes or some lib?

Comment: try to change *b.Games.Where(l => l.League == league)* to *b.Games.Where(l => l.League.Id == leagueId)*, I don't think entities for sql support to compare the entity itself on the query, also this removes the need to search first for the League entity.

Comment: This exception is thrown when the given .NET queryable cannot be (by the EF generation engine) converted into a native SQL query. Searching for ["ef notsupportedexception"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework%5D+notsupportedexception) should yield many duplicates/hints.

Comment: `SeasonDate == seasonYear` are you comparing a `DateTime` to an `int`? Also, you should be able to combine your `.Where()` clauses together.

Comment: Gusman that fixed the problem if you want to make your comment an answer ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.Games.Where(l => l.League == league)
```

This line of code is where you are probably getting the error. You cannot do object comparisons inside EF query because EF needs to convert your LINQ statements to SQL queries. You should better compare objects by their ids.

```
db.Games.Where(l => l.League.Id == league.Id)
```

should work.